# Yii Multiform and table input

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i have 2 tables in MySQL:

1)object 
-id
-name

2) object_info 
-id
-object_id
-info
-description
-type

where each object have at 20 records on object_info:

How to realize tabular input???

on contoller

```
    public function actionCreate() {
         $object = new Object();
         $object_info = new ObjectInfo();
         if(isset($_POST['Ojbect'])) { //how to check POST?

         }
         $this->render('form', array('object'=>$object, 'object_info'=>$object_info);
    }
```

on view how build form? ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle complex form with multiple models and tabular input in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571549/how-to-handle-complex-form-with-multiple-models-and-tabular-input-in-yii)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576776/in-yii-is-there-a-way-to-validate-tabular-input-with-cactiveform?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685138/save-multiple-tabular-input-in-yii